# How to write a search function to get the path of the desired file?

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, recursion

I have a directory structure that looks like the image.
[image: Folder Structure]

This structure is organised in a form of `objects`. `File` objects are each in the form: `{type:'file', name:'file a1'}` for example. `Folder`objects are like File objects, but they have an extra key `children` which is an array of sub folders/files.

Here's a console log of the `rootFolder` object from the image before:

[image: screenshot of console.log(rootFolder)]

**The goal:**
What I want is to write a search function that returns the path for a specific file in the form of an array. For example, if I were to search for `file c3`, the result would be: `['folder a3', 'folder b4']`.

I have tried many things, but recursion isn't my strongest suit.

The code could be in *javascript* or *python*; what I care about is the **algorithm** itself.

Here is the code used to generate `rootFolder`:

```js
// defining constants
const TYPES = {FILE: 'file', FOLDER: 'folder'}
const FILE_NAMES = {
  FILE_A1:'file a1', 
  FILE_A2:'file a2', 
  FILE_A4:'file a4',
  FILE_B2:'file b2',
  FILE_B3:'file b3',
  FILE_C1:'file c1',
  FILE_C2:'file c2',
  FILE_C3:'file c3',
  FILE_C4:'file c4',
  FILE_C5:'file c5',
}
const FOLDER_NAMES = {
  ROOT_FOLDER:'root folder',
  FOLDER_A3:'folder a3',
  FOLDER_B1:'folder b1',
  FOLDER_B4:'folder b4'
}
// defining classes
class File {
  constructor(type, name) {
    this.name = name
    this.type = type
  }
}
class Folder {
  constructor (type, name, children) {
    this.name = name
    this.type = type
    this.children = children
  }
}
// defining file objects
const fileA1 = new File(TYPES.FILE, FILE_NAMES.FILE_A1)
const fileA2 = new File(TYPES.FILE, FILE_NAMES.FILE_A2)
const fileA4 = new File(TYPES.FILE, FILE_NAMES.FILE_A4)
const fileB2 = new File(TYPES.FILE, FILE_NAMES.FILE_B2)
const fileB3 = new File(TYPES.FILE, FILE_NAMES.FILE_B3)
const fileC1 = new File(TYPES.FILE, FILE_NAMES.FILE_C1)
const fileC2 = new File(TYPES.FILE, FILE_NAMES.FILE_C2)
const fileC3 = new File(TYPES.FILE, FILE_NAMES.FILE_C3)
const fileC4 = new File(TYPES.FILE, FILE_NAMES.FILE_C4)
const fileC5 = new File(TYPES.FILE, FILE_NAMES.FILE_C5)
// defining folder objects
const folderB1 = new Folder(TYPES.FOLDER, FOLDER_NAMES.FOLDER_B1, [fileC1, fileC2])
const folderB4 = new Folder(TYPES.FOLDER, FOLDER_NAMES.FOLDER_B4, [fileC3, fileC4, fileC5])
const folderA3 = new Folder(TYPES.FOLDER, FOLDER_NAMES.FOLDER_A3, [folderB1, fileB2, fileB3, folderB4])
const rootFolder = new Folder(TYPES.FOLDER, FOLDER_NAMES.ROOT_FOLDER, [fileA1, fileA2, folderA3, fileA4])

console.log(rootFolder);
```

Comment: I don't get how ```file c3``` connects with ```folder a3 and folder b4```. folder b4 is the value of the "name" key in ```file c3``` object group but what about ```folder a3``` how does it connect with ```file c3```? Maybe folder with array number 3?

Comment: @seriously I have added the code used to generate `rootFolder`. `file c3` is a child of `folder b4` which is a child of `folder a3`

Comment: The essence of what you want to do is called a [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) — now you know where to find some algorithms…

Comment: Have you tried something like DFS/BFS? Should be the easiest solution imo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**remove indrection**

Before we get started, first remove the myriad of [indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection) caused by over 20 variables. We can use just two (2) classes and a single `root` -

```js
class File {
  constructor(type, name) {
    this.name = name
    this.type = type
  }
}

class Folder {
  constructor(type, name, children) {
    this.name = name
    this.type = type
    this.children = children
  }
}

const root =
  new Folder("folder", "root folder", [
    new File("file", "file a1"),
    new File("file", "file a2"),
    new Folder("folder", "folder a3", [
      new Folder("folder", "folder b1", [
        new File("file", "file c1"),
        new File("file", "file c2")
      ]),
      new File("file", "file b2"),
      new File("file", "file b3"),
      new Folder("folder", "folder b4", [
        new File("file", "file c3"),
        new File("file", "file c4"),
        new File("file", "file c5")
      ])
    ]),
    new File("file", "file a4")
  ])
```

**remove redundancy**

`TYPES.FILE` and `TYPES.FOLDER` are unneeded if you have separate `File` and `Folder` classes. Each instance will already have an associated type -

```js
class File {
  constructor(name) { // ✅ type not necessary
    this.name = name
  }
}

class Folder {
  constructor (name, children) { // ✅ type not necessary
    this.name = name
    this.children = children
  }
}

const root =
  new Folder("root folder", [
    new File("file a1"),
    new File("file a2"),
    new Folder("folder a3", [
      new Folder("folder b1", [
        new File("file c1"),
        new File("file c2")
      ]),
      new File("file b2"),
      new File("file b3"),
      new Folder("folder b4", [
        new File("file c3"),
        new File("file c4"),
        new File("file c5")
      ])
    ]),
    new File("file a4")
  ])
```

**multiple return values**

Because file systems support folders or files with the same name (at different hierarchies), it's important that our `search` algorithm can scan for *all* possible matches of the query. For a complete example, let's include `file c3` in `folder b1` *and* `folder b4`. When searching for this file, we expect to see both paths returned -

```js
const root =
  new Folder("root folder", [
    new File("file a1"),
    new File("file a2"),
    new Folder("folder a3", [
      new Folder("folder b1", [
        new File("file c1"),
        new File("file c2"),
        new File("file c3")  // ✅ could have the same name
      ]),
      new File("file b2"),
      new File("file b3"),
      new Folder("folder b4", [
        new File("file c3"), // ✅ could have the same name
        new File("file c4"),
        new File("file c5")
      ])
    ]),
    new File("file a4")
  ])
```

**the algorithm**

Now that we've fixed the other issues with the code, let's write `search(t, query)`. We can do this using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. If `t` is a File and its `name` matches the `query`, yield the singleton result `[t]`
2. (inductive) `t` is not a File. If `t` is a Folder and its `name` matches the `query` input the singleton result `[t]`. And for all `child` of `t.children`, for all `path` of the recursive sub-problem `search(child, query)`, prepend `t` to the `path` and yield.
3. (inductive) `t` is neither a File nor a Folder. Throw a type error to notify the caller.

```js
function* search(t, query) {
  switch(t?.constructor) {
    case File:
      if (t.name == query)
        yield [t]
      break
    case Folder:
      if (t.name == query)
        yield [t]
      for (const child of t.children)
        for (const path of search(child, query))
          yield [t, ...path]
      break
    default:
      throw Error(`cannot search unsupported type ${t}`)
  }
}
```

Here's some search examples -

```js
for (const path of search(root, "root folder"))
  console.log([".", ...path.map(f => f.name)].join("/"))
```

```
./root folder
```

```js
for (const path of search(root, "file a1"))
  console.log([".", ...path.map(f => f.name)].join("/"))
```

```
./root folder/file a1
```

Multiple paths are returned when a file or folder is found multiple times -

```js
for (const path of search(root, "file c3"))
  console.log([".", ...path.map(f => f.name)].join("/"))
```

```
./root folder/folder a3/folder b1/file c3
./root folder/folder a3/folder b4/file c3
```

When a file or folder cannot be found, no output is given -

```js
for (const path of search(root, "file Q"))
  console.log([".", ...path.map(f => f.name)].join("/"))
```

```
⚠️ no output
```

**caller decides effect**

By yielding a sequence of `Folder` and `File` objects, our `search` algorithm remains generic and reusable. Strings are not assembled by default and nothing is logged to the console. If the caller wishes to create a `/`-separated path, that is demonstrated above. Options for a different effect are left for the caller to decide.

**only one result**

Using a generator is perfect for `search` because the caller can choose to consume all matches or any number of them. In this example, we use a generic `first` to return only the *first* match. Note the generator is canceled immediately after a match is found and no additional work is done by the cpu -

```js
function first(iter) {
  for (const v of iter)
    return v
}

const match = first(search(root, "file c3"))

if (match)
  console.log("found:", match.map(f => f.name).join("/"))
else
  console.error("no match found")
```

```
found: root folderfolder a3/folder b1/file c3
```

Make sure you do a proper null-check if using `first` in this way as it is possible that `search` yields nothing when no match is found -

```js
const match = first(search(root, "ZZZ"))

if (match)
  console.log("found:", match.map(f => f.name).join("/"))
else
  console.error("no match found")
```

```
no match found
```

**higher-order search**

In the original algorithm matches are determined using `==`. The algorithm could be more useful if we allow the caller to specify what constitutes a match -

```js
function* search(t, query) {
  switch(t?.constructor) {
    case File:
      if (Boolean(query(t.name))) // ✅ query is a func
        yield [t]
      break
    case Folder:
      if (Boolean(query(t.name))) // ✅ query is a func
        yield [t]
      for (const child of t.children)
        for (const path of search(child, query))
          yield [t, ...path]
      break
    default:
      throw Error(`cannot search unsupported type ${t}`)
  }
}
```

Let's find all files that start with `file c` -

```js
for (const path of search(root, filename => filename.startsWith("file c")))
  console.log([".", ...path.map(f => f.name)].join("/"))
```

```
./root folder/folder a3/folder b1/file c1
./root folder/folder a3/folder b1/file c2
./root folder/folder a3/folder b1/file c3
./root folder/folder a3/folder b4/file c3
./root folder/folder a3/folder b4/file c4
./root folder/folder a3/folder b4/file c5
```

**specialization**

With a higher-order `search` function, you can easily implement things like `searchByString`. This is known as a *specialization* -

```js
function searchByString(t, query) {
  return search(t, filename => filename == query)
}
```

```js
for (const path of searchByString(root, "file c3"))
  console.log([".", ...path.map(f => f.name)].join("/"))
```

```
./root folder/folder a3/folder b1/file c3
./root folder/folder a3/folder b4/file c3
```

**code demo**

The code above has been condensed so you can see it all in one place. **Run** the snippet and verify the output -

```js
class File { constructor(name) { this.name = name } }

class Folder { constructor(name, children) { this.name = name;  this.children = children } }

function* search(t, query) {
  switch(t?.constructor) {
    case File: if (Boolean(query(t.name))) yield [t];  break
    case Folder: if (Boolean(query(t.name))) yield [t]; for (const child of t.children) for (const path of search(child, query)) yield [t, ...path]; break
    default: throw Error(`cannot search unsupported type ${t}`)
  }
}

function searchByString(t, query) {
  return search(t, filename => filename == query)
}

const relative = (path) => [".", ...path.map(f => f.name)].join("/")

const root = new Folder("root folder", [new File("file a1"), new File("file a2"), new Folder("folder a3", [new Folder("folder b1", [new File("file c1"), new File("file c2"), new File("file c3")]), new File("file b2"), new File("file b3"), new Folder("folder b4", [new File("file c3"), new File("file c4"), new File("file c5")])]), new File("file a4")])

console.log("== exact match ==")
for (const path of search(root, filename => filename == "root folder"))
  console.log(relative(path))

console.log("== starts with 'file c' ==")
for (const path of search(root, filename => filename.startsWith("file c")))
  console.log(relative(path))

console.log("== searchByString ==")
for (const path of searchByString(root, "file c3"))
  console.log(relative(path))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
== exact match ==
./root folder
== starts with 'file c' ==
./root folder/folder a3/folder b1/file c1
./root folder/folder a3/folder b1/file c2
./root folder/folder a3/folder b1/file c3
./root folder/folder a3/folder b4/file c3
./root folder/folder a3/folder b4/file c4
./root folder/folder a3/folder b4/file c5
== searchByString ==
./root folder/folder a3/folder b1/file c3
./root folder/folder a3/folder b4/file c3
```

**python**

`search` is written exactly the same in Python -

```py
class file:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

class folder:
  def __init__(self, name, children):
    self.name = name
    self.children = children

def search(t, query):
  if isinstance(t, file):
    if t.name == query:
      yield [t]
  elif isinstance(t, folder):
    if t.name == query:
      yield [t]
    for child in t.children:
      for path in search(child, query):
        yield [t, *path]
  else:
    raise TypeError("unsupported", t)
```

If you are using Python 3.10, there are some new features available to you. Adjust `search` to take advantage of the new structural `match..case` syntax -

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generator, Union

Ftree = Union["file", "folder"]

@dataclass
class file:
  name: str

@dataclass
class folder:
  name: str
  children: list[Ftree]

def search(t: Ftree, query: str) -> Generator[list[Ftree], None, None]:
  match t:
    case file(name):
      if name == query: yield [t]
    case folder(name, children):
      if name == query: yield [t]
      for child in t.children:
        for path in search(child, query):
          yield [t, *path]
    case _:
      raise TypeError("unsupported", t)
```

Given a tree -

```
root = \
  folder("root folder", [
    file("file a1"),
    file("file a2"),
    folder("folder a3", [
      folder("folder b1", [
        file("file c1"),
        file("file c2"),
        file("file c3")
      ]),
      file("file b2"),
      file("file b3"),
      folder("folder b4", [
        file("file c3"),
        file("file c4"),
        file("file c5")
      ])
    ]),
    file("file a4")
  ])
```

Both implementations behave identically -

```py
for path in search(root, "root folder"):
  print("/".join([".", *map(lambda f: f.name, path)]))
```

```
./root folder
```

```py
for path in search(root, "file c3"):
  print("/".join([".", *map(lambda f: f.name, path)]))
```

```
./root folder/folder a3/folder b1/file c3
./root folder/folder a3/folder b4/file c3
```

Comment: As always, a beautiful answer!  A possible extension would be to pass the full path of the item to the predicate, either in place of the name (less ergonomic, but simpler) or as a second, somewhat redundant, argument (the reverse.)

Comment: thanks Scott. that would definitely allow for more high-powered searches, like specifying path segments for matching criteria and globbing. A good exercise for the reader :D

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mulan for the great illustration. Not only did you answer my question, but you also helped me improve my current code. Cheers